# Where does Charles Xavier's seizure power come from?

Tags: x-men-cinematic-universe, wolverine, marvel, logan

In Logan, Charles Xavier suffers from dementia. He has seizures which seem to cause shock waves, resulting in headaches, and time slowing down. Does he have this power in the comics?

Answer (score 2):

It is worth mentioning that he does exhibit this ability several times in other X-Men movies, so there is a cinematic precedent. On at least two occasions he freezes an entire room of people so he can pass through it unnoticed or to deescalate a situation and pass through it unnoticed. Presumably he allows people to breathe though. And - albeit while he is connected to an amplifier, Cerebro or Apocalypse - he is able to affect the minds of everyone in the world, which is central to the plots of X2 and X-Men: Apocalypse.

This power probably isn't portrayed in the comics very often, since it is difficult to portray people frozen in place in a format that is frozen in place.